# How to take a portrait for a resume?

Tags: lighting, portrait

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Advice to do a good photo for my CV](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8876/advice-to-do-a-good-photo-for-my-cv)

Hi everybody.
Quick question: How would you proceed for a resume photo? If you think something would be a good idea even if it's not the *standard* way to do it, please contribute :)

Every detail counts!

- Focal length
- Lighting
- Background
- Crop
- Etc.