# Which color for a job interview portrait?

Tags: lighting, portrait, color, business

For a job interview portrait, I need to make a picture that reflects **leadership, creativity and flexibility.**

What color or colors should I use? 
Also, after pick up the color, should I use a tone high, or more darkness?

I'm coming from this post as reference:

[How do I take a good portrait for a CV or resume?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8876/how-do-i-take-a-good-portrait-for-a-cv-or-resume)

and this one:
http://static1.creativosonline.org/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/psicologia-del-color.jpg

Comment: I don't think that colors can define leadership etc. Have you tried [googling examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=portatrait+for+cv&oq=portatrait+for+cv&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2555j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=portrait+for+cv&spell=1)?

Comment: Yes, I think about more with a psycologic review.

Comment: color of background has little to do with effect if model is ugly or picture is awful. If not, then attention will be on the face. Just don't use acid green

Comment: wow, I seriously thought about use that color because one of my colleges uses it: https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrink_200_200/p/1/005/0b5/15a/1ec218c.jpg

Comment: I was thinking along this line: [acid green](https://www.google.com/search?q=acid+green&oq=acid+green&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1367j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: This is really not about photography.  It might belong on the workplace stack, or psychology.

Comment: @OlinLathrop What? It's _prima facie_ about photography.

Comment: @matt: This is about what color to make the background, not how to achieve that, or any other look and feel, once you've decided what you want.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Deciding what you want, and what composition (including composition will work to fill that want) is part of photography.

Comment: I tried to complement the question referenced.

Comment: The implied question *"which color represents leadership"* would apply in non-photographic situations like choosing a shirt or wall-paint. So it is likely that the best place to ask that question would be somewhere other than a place that is only one of many that might apply that knowledge.

Comment: With that consideration anything in photography that is not about technology will be applied in other situation. So close photography and make a tech-optic stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, *leadership, creativity and flexibility* are not best conveyed by the backdrop color of a headshot.

Note that I said headshot, as that is what I would typically recommend for any resume/CV image.

Instead I think that it is important to consider your audience. Are you(or the user of the image) applying for a position as a manager in a corporate environment? Then use a soft background with pleasing soft shadows that don't  take away from the subject. What color the background is less important then capturing a technically high quality image. Make sure the subject is wearing colors that compliment the background.  If you are applying for a creative position you might want to skip the headshot all together as well as any rules and try for unique.

Comment: Well, you told me things that I never think, this is a helpful answer. It was for a client but this will help me a lot in the future. Thanks! :)

Comment: If it's a management position, I recommend a nice orange jumpsuit on a white background with horizontal black lines, under the premise that the other C*Os will see it and immediately know that you're one of them.  :-D