# matching field of view between apsc and full frame

Tags: focal-length, full-frame, aps-c, comparison

I'm sure this is a dumb question. I'm upgrading from a sony a6 aps-c to a sony a7Rii full frame and trying to determine which focal length of FE primes I want. I'm using my aps-c a6 as a reference to make that decision and it leads me to this question:

Is the field of view the same for an aps-c body with an apsc lens on it and a full-frame body with a full frame (FE) lens on it?

Thanks very much!

Comment: small point of order - there is no Sony α6. Presume you mean Sony NEX-6. (Admittedly, it does fall under the Sony Alpha family, but that's not the model name.)

Comment: Practical demonstration of this - https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/97747/57929

Answer (score 3):

> Is the field of view the same for an aps-c body with an aps-c lens on it and a full-frame body with a full frame (FE) lens on it?

Not if both lenses are the same focal length. Focal length is a property of the lens, not of the sensor size. Angle-of-view (AoV) is a property of the focal length and the sensor size combined. AoV is what we use crop factors for when comparing what focal length we need to get the same angle-of-view using different sensor sizes.

Look at it this way. If you have a 50mm FF lens on an APS-C camera and a 50mm APS-C lens on an APS-C camera, the focal lengths of *both* lenses is exactly the same, the angle-of-view you'll see with *both* is exactly the same, and *both* 50mm focal lengths need to be multiplied by the crop factor to tell you what angle of view you will have compared to a FF camera. In the case of Sony APS-C cameras, **any** 50mm lens will give the same angle-of-view on a Sony APS-C camera as what you'll get with a 75mm FF lens on a FF camera.

It doesn't matter if the lens you are using on your APS-C camera is an APS-C only lens or if it is a FF lens, the same focal length will give you the same angle-of-view on the same APS-C camera.¹

**For whatever angle-of-view you see on your APS-C camera with a particular focal length lens (APS-C or FF), if you want the same angle-of-view using a FF camera you need to multiply the focal length of the lens you're using on your APS-C camera by 1.5X.**

18mm on APS-C is the same AoV as 27mm on FF, so get a 28mm lens.
24mm on APS-C is the same AoV as 36mm on FF, so get a 35mm lens.
35mm on APs-C is the same AoV as 52.5mm on FF, so get a 50mm or 55mm lens.
50mm on APS-C is the same AoV as 75mm on FF, so get a 70mm or 85mm lens.
70mm on APS-C is the same AoV as 105mm on FF, so get a 100mm or 105mm lens.
85mm on APS-C is the same AoV as 127.5mm on FF, so get a 135mm lens.
90mm on APS-C is the same AoV as 135mm on FF, so get a 135mm lens.
100mm on APS-C is the same AoV as 150mm on FF, so get a 150mm lens (if you can find one).
135mm on APS-C is the same AoV as 202.5mm on FF, so get a 200mm lens.
200mm on APS-C is the same AoV as 300mm on FF, so get a 300mm lens.

It's that simple.

<sub>¹ Within the limits of the actual versus marketed focal length of the lens, that is. Most lenses are rounded up or down to the nearest "standard" focal length. Both a 33mm lens and a 37mm lens will be marketed as 35mm lenses. Both a 189mm lens and a 203mm lens will be marketed as 200mm lenses, and so on.</sub>

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer, Michael. It is much appreciated. This makes sense to me!

Comment: I think you  have a typo for the 24mm on APS-C. It should be 36mm on FF, not 26mm.

Comment: @EricS Yep. It's fixed now. Thanks! (P.S. You missed where I typed 137.5mm when I should have typed 127.5mm.)

Comment: I won't tell if you won't.